# odds of all 15 MLB teams winning at home

Tags: statistics

The recent rare case of all $15$ MLB teams winning at home was reported as odds of $1$ out of $32{,}768$.  I thought the calculation would be $0.5 \times 0.5 \times 0.5 \times \cdots$ for the $15$ teams, but I got a much higher number (the digits were correct but my result was around $327{,}000$.

Comment: Clarification: There are $30$ teams, so $15$ games can be played simultaneously.  There would then be $15$ home teams. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3):

You must have miscalculated. Assuming that each team independently wins with probability $\frac12$, the probability (not odds) of all $15$ home teams winning is

$$
\left(\frac12\right)^{15}=\frac1{2^{15}}=\frac1{32768}\;.
$$

P.S.: As Michael Hardy pointed out in the comments, the unrealistic assumption that the teams win with probability $\frac12$ isn't necessary; it suffices that the probability for each team to be scheduled to play at home on this day is $\frac12$. However, as Brian Tung has pointed out, this requires the similarly unrealistic assumption that there is no advantage to playing at home.

In any case, if the probability $2^{-15}$ was reported, some such assumption about games being won by the home teams with probability $\frac12$ must have been made.

Comment: Suppose we assume some teams are stronger than others, but we have a uniformly distributed random pairing. The most extreme case of that is that there is no randomness except in the pairing. A slightly less unrealistic problem might be this: The god of baseball has decreed in advance for each pair of teams which will defeat the other if they should play against each other, but the relation "A beats B" might not be transitive.  Then again let the randomness reside only in the choice of pairing. Then what is the probability that the pairing we get is one in which every home team wins?${}\quad{}$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$or besides the pairing we also choose at random which will be the home team, and the advance decree of the baseball deity is for _ordered_ pairs, the first component of the pair being the home team. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: +1.  There's a non-zero home-field advantage, though.  I think your solution suffices for most puzzle purposes, but with the "right" details, one can make this arbitrarily cumbersome. :-)

Comment: Historically, home teams win about 54% of the time.  This doesn't seem like a big difference but it actually changes the expected value quite a bit.  See: http://www.baseball-reference.com/blog/archives/352

In particular, the expected value is roughly 56.8 years instead of 180... which is a big difference relative our life spans.

Comment: @BrianTung : The home-field advantage will have been attended to by the aforementioned decree of the god of baseball. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I'm not sure I see that.  Suppose the teams are in fact evenly matched, but home-field advantage is so extreme as to give the home team a $99$ percent chance of winning.  Then the probability of all the home teams winning is $0.99^{15}$.  That's a simple case, but let's say that each team has in fact a different strength, and home-field advantage adds to that strength.  I still think you can make this problem very hairy, if you choose.